# python sqlite3 disk I/O error with WAL journal mode on a reader and writer application

Tags: python, sqlite

I have 2 python3 applications, one that writes data to a sqlite3 db and one that reads it. The writer will frequently write large pandas DataFrames about every minute to the db - the data being written is ~500,000 rows x ~50 columns. The writer is using `journal_mode=WAL;` as well as `wal_autocheckpoint=0;`, with the latter being due to an error in checkpoints with data this large and pandas' `df.to_sql()` method. The writer is working fine - however, when I attempt to read from this db while it is being written to, I get the error `disk I/O error` from sqlite3. I am not sure what is missing, I have tried reading other samples of this error but it seems to encompass a lot.

Below are samples of the reader/writer interacting with this db - sqlite version is 3.31.1

`writer.py`

Connection code: `self.db_con_data = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(self.sqlite_path))`

Function that writes data:

```
def write_to_sqlite(self, df):
    #Create db cursor - connection was made at program start.
    cur = self.db_con_data.cursor()
    cur.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;')
    cur.execute('PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint=0;')

    #Write to sqlite db
    df.to_sql(name={self.sqlite_current_table}, con=self.db_con_data, if_exists='append', index=False)
        
    #Create checkpoint and close cursor so other dbs can use this
    cur.execute('PRAGMA wal_checkpoint;')
    cur.close()
```

`reader.py`

For the reader, I can create the connection and cursor objects fine, but executing any cursor statements causes the above disk I/O error.

Connection code: `self.dbcon = sqlite3.connect(self.dbcon_path, check_same_thread=False)`

Function that reads data:

```
def update_data(self):
    #Connection was made at program start
    cur = self.dbcon.cursor() #This runs fine
    cur.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;') #This throws the disk I/O error
    data = cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM '{self.dbcon_table}'").fetchall()
```